# IBM DS3400 - how replace a good disk

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, ibm

I've to replace all my disks with other bigger ones.
I read in the manual:

```
Never hot-swap a drive when its associated green activity LED is
flashing. Hot-swap a drive only when its associated amber status LED is lit and
not flashing
```

But how can i set my disks in fault state?

Always in the manual:

```
If you want to remove a hard disk drive that is not in a failed or bypass state,
always use the Storage Manager Client program either to place the drive in
a failed state or to place the array that is associated with the drive (or drives)
in an offline state before you remove the drive from the storage subsystem.
```

But in the SMC there's not a "button" to set a disk in fault mode!
can you help me?

Comment: Guaranteed way to get it into fault mode: yank it out

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question about setting disks in fault state: the Storage Manager Client allows you to maually fail a disk. In the main menu, go to "Advanced" -> "Recovery" -> "Fail drive"

Answer (score 0):

First, destroy the raid. That should make all the raid disks become "spare" or "unassigned" or something. Second, remove all the disks in the raid. Third, add the new disks into the system. Fourth, make the new disks into a new raid. If you have data in the array, you need to copy it somewhere else to do this.

A few things I can't tell from your question whether you know:

- If you replace a small drive in a raid with a larger one, you do not get any new free space in your raid
- You should never mix drive speeds in an array- if it's made from 10k RPM drives now, you shouldn't add a 7.2k RPM drive to it
- You can add disks to a raid without downtime, but you can not remove them

Comment: ok thanks, any other suggest than not lose any data?

Answer (score 0):

i googled for a while and no way to get a stait answer other than copy data or make a flash copy somwhere and delete the array and replace disk..etc
those solutions are useless in a production situation where you are short of space and nowhere to copy all the data, at the same time no downtime is allowed .

so i went back to the basic behaviour of a raid 5 and used common sence

In my case 
DS3400 12 slots (300 GB each) including the spare
to upgrade to 600 GB disk ( of course same speed same brand etc ...)
first i replaced the spare disk slot 12 (hot swap) and in the GUI 
configure->configure hot spares
i unassigned the old disk and assigned the new one
the status indicator went back to green.
next step i started replacing the disk slot 11
once you remove it wait until the spare is activated (starts blinking) 
then insert the new disk in the slot 11
then wait until the data reconstitution is completed on the spare (in the GUI "task in progress" will show 0)
then in the GUI : MODIFY - > replace drives
you replace the missong one withe the new inserted drive
at this step a copy back will start from the spare to the new insterted disk
wait until it's copmleted and the satus is back to green
repeate the same steps with the next disk

once i had completed those steps with the last disk, the extra free capacity has shown

and i added new logical drive using the GUI :
configure -> create array and logical drives

it worked fine